# ARM: Floating point (VFP) instructions won't work when pushing into the stack

Tags: assembly, floating-point, arm, libc

I am trying to print some floating point values in ARM Assembly. As long as I don't push stuff into the stack the value gets printed correctly. If I push something it just prints 0.

This code works because it doesn't push stuff into the stack.

```
    .global main
    .func main

main:
  LDR R0, value_address @ Get address of value
  VLDR S14, [R0]        @ Move value into single precision S14 register
  VCVT.F64.F32 D0, S14  @ Convert single precision to double precision for printf

  LDR R0, =string       @ Give R0 the address of the string
  VMOV R2, R3, D0       @ Get the double precision value stored in registers
  BL printf             @ call printf

  MOV R7, #1            @ Exit syscall
  SWI 0

value_address:  .word value

.data
value:  .float 3.141592
string: .asciz "Floating point value is: %f\n"
```

I get the following output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/aal $ gcc -o printfp printfp.s
pi@raspberrypi:~/aal $ ./printfp
Floating point value is: 3.141592
```

Then I modify it to use the stack to save the `LR` and it doesn't work properly. I've done it before without VFP instructions and it works.

```
    .global main
    .func main

main:
    PUSH {LR}

    LDR R0, value_address   @ Get address of value
    VLDR S14, [R0]          @ Move value into single precision S14 register
    VCVT.F64.F32 D0, S14    @ Convert single precision to double precision for printf

    LDR R0, =string         @ Give R0 the address of the string
    VMOV R2, R3, D0         @ Get the double precision value stored in registers
    BL printf               @ call printf

    POP {PC}
    BX LR

value_address:  .word value

.data
value:  .float 3.141592
string: .asciz "Floating point value is: %f\n"
```

And now I get this value:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/aal $ gcc -o printfp printfp.s
pi@raspberrypi:~/aal $ ./printfp
Floating point value is: 0.000000
```

So I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Could it be a stack misalignment issue? The EABI requires the stack to be 8 byte aligned.